# Convert to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list containing another list. I want to loop inside the primary list and then inside all the secondary lists, until the id of an object from the secondary list matches the required id. The primary list should then be returned.

Is it possible to convert the following code to LINQ?

```
var myID = "1"; //Just a stub
var tempItem = null;

//Loop each itemA from list A
foreach (var itemA in listA)
{
    //Loop each itemB from itemA.listB
    foreach (var itemB in itemA.listB)
    {
        //Compare IDs
        if (itemB.ID == myID)
        {
            //If IDs of itemB match, return itemA
            tempItem = itemA;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is myID defined?

Comment: It could be of any value, not of significant importance.

Comment: You probably want to use `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 5):

```
tempItem = listA.FirstOrDefault(a=> a.itemB.Any(b=>b.ID==myID))
```

Comment: note: this solution does not do EXACTLY the same as the code: the OP's code keeps looping over listA after the first time tempItem has been assigned. My code returns directly once the first has been found. However, from the comments I understand that my solution is what the OP intended, not what he wrote (the break will only exit the inner loop, but not the outer).

Comment: To add to your note, you can replicate the same functionality by using `LastOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 2):

This will return `listA` item or null if no list is found:

```
var tempItem = listA.FirstOrDefault(l => l.listB.Exists(x => x.ID == myID));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try the following code

```
 var result = itemA.FirstOrDefault(p => p.listB.Find(t => t.ID == myID) != null));
```

This should return null if no matching items are found. Otherwise, will return the first matching object. To get a collection of matching objects, you just have to replace the FirstOrDefault method with Where

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var itemA in ListA.Where(itemA => itemA.B.Any(itemB => itemB.ID == myID)))
{
    tempItem = itemA;
}
```

Comment: 1 LINQ and 1 foreach. OP wants this in LINQ only.